# Error with seting keyval default values with def

Tags: macros, key-value, spanish

First of all, sorry for my english level.

I'm trying to do a personalized command with key value parameters through keyval package. It's my first attempt and probably can be better forms to do it.

I made a file included into principal file via input command. In the first part of that file I would like to have a little description of my personal commands and the configuration if it's necessary.

I made a new command (\imagen) to include pictures and my intention es that it works like:

```
\imagen[key-value options]{file name}{caption}
```

The keys I would like to use are:

- carpeta= folder where I save de images
- ancho = width
- escala = scale
- aqui --> bolean to force position to H. Normal is htb
- etiqueta = label for ref. In default mode it's file name

The definition of that command is:

```
% INCLUIR IMAGENES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Creación de las claves
\makeatletter
\define@key{Imagen}{carpeta}{\def\Imagen@carpeta{#1}}
\define@key{Imagen}{ancho}{\def\Imagen@ancho{#1}}
\define@key{Imagen}{escala}{\def\Imagen@escala{#1}}
\define@key{Imagen}{aqui}[true]{\def\Imagen@aqui{#1}}
\define@key{Imagen}{etiqueta}{\def\Imagen@etiqueta{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Valores por defecto
\setkeys{Imagen}{\ImagenDefecto}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Definición de la Macro
\newcommand{\imagen}[3][]{
 %se empieza un grupo para que no guarde
 \begingroup
  \setkeys{Imagen}{#1}
  \ifdef\Imagen@carpeta%
    {\def\Imagen@fichero{{\Imagen@carpeta#2}}}%
    {\def\Imagen@fichero{#2}}
  \ifdef\Imagen@aqui%
    {\begin{figure}[H]}%
    {\begin{figure}[htb]}
      \begin{center}
        \ifdef\Imagen@anchura%
          {\includegraphics[width=\Imagen@ancho]{\Imagen@fichero}}%
          {\ifdef\Imagen@escala%
            {\includegraphics[scale=\Imagen@escala]{\Imagen@fichero}}
            {\includegraphics{\Imagen@fichero}}
          }
        \captionof{figure}{#3}
        \ifdef\Imagen@etiqueta%
          {\label{\Imagen@etiqueta}}%
          {\label{#2}}
      \end{center}
    \end{figure}
 \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

As you can see, I put \setkeys{Imagen}{\ImagenDefecto} where \ImagenDefecto it's a definition that comes from the frist part of that file where I do a litle description how it works the command and try to configure it.

To do the configurations I use:

```
\def\ImagenDefecto{aqui, carpeta=img}
```

It not work if I use the = symbol in the definition, but if I put the same text directly in key value command \setkeys{Imagen}{aqui, carpeta=img} works perfectly.

The error is:

```
! Package keyval Error: aqui, escala=img undefined.
```

I was trying to deactivate packets that I think can be a problem like Babel (all is in spanish) and I don't know what can be the problem.

If do you like, I'm doing this to have a template and I put all the code into github: https://github.com/pepramon/plantilla-latex

Thanks to all.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: `\setkeys` does not expand the macro `\ImagenDefecto` in order to split it and sees a key named `aqui, escala=img` (which does not exist,however), but not two separate keys

Comment: I don't believe that your Boolean can work 'perfectly' either way, because `\ifdef` is not testing the value at all. You probably want an `\ifaqui` here, so that you can treat it as a Boolean in the code.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at the `easyfig` package. It provides a very similar macro called `\Figure`.

Comment: I dont know about `easyfig` package!!!! to obtain the funcionality that I whas searching is really easy now: `\newcommand{\imagen}[3][]{\Figure[placement=H,caption={#3},label=#2,#1]{#2}}` and works perfectly. I test and you can rename de `label`!!!!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\ImagenDefecto` needs to be expanded to reveal the syntax characters comma and equal sign of the key value syntax. It can be expanded in a lot of ways. For example with lots of `\expandafter`:

```
\expandafter\setkeys\expandafter{\expandafter I\expandafter m ...\expandafter}\expandafter{\ImagenDefecto}
```

Since `\expandafter` can only jump over one token, the part before the key value list can be put in a macro. This way, a setup command is defined for free:

```
\newcommand*{\ImagenSetup}{%
  \setkeys{Imagen}%
}
\expandafter\ImagenSetup\expandafter{\ImagenDefecto}
```

Also, after the definition of `\ImagenSetup`, the configuration can be done by

```
\ImagenSetup{aqui, carpeta=img}
```

### Option declarations via package `kvoptions`

The option declarations can be simplified by package `kvoptions`:

```
\usepackage{kvoptions}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=Imagen,
  prefix=Imagen@,
}
\DeclareStringOption{carpeta}
\DeclareStringOption{ancho}
\DeclareStringOption{escala}
\DeclareBoolOption{aqui}
\DeclareStringOption{etiqueta}
\newcommand*{\ImagenSetup}{\setkeys{Imagen}}
```

The options can then be used in this way:

```
\makeatletter

% String options are initialized to the empty string by default.
\ifx\Imagen@carpeta\@empty
  % empty string
\else
  % non-empty
\fi

% Boolean options are initialized to false by default.
\ifImagen@aqui
  % "aqui" or "aqui=true"
\else
  % default or "aqui=false"
\fi
\makeatother
```

Comment: I try and with a lot of `\expandafter` as you say and works, but finally, I use `easyfig` package as says Skillmon because I preserve the options of `\includegraphics` and I obtain the functionality I was searching with only one `\newcommand`.  
Lots of thanks for your help

Comment: Also `\newcommand{\ImagenSetup}{\expandafter\Imagen@Setup\expandafter}` and `\newcommand{\Imagen@Setup}{\setkeys{Imagen}`, so one can simply call `\ImagenSetup{\ImagenDefecto}`

Comment: @egreg Then: `\newcommand{\ImageSetup}[1]{\expandafter\Imagen@Setup\expandafter{#1}}`. Otherwise `\ImagenSetup\ImagenDefecto` would not work as expected, because the last `\expandafter` would jump too far to the token after `\ImageDefecto`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I was under the assumption `\ImagenSetup` is always called with braces around the argument, as it can also be used with a standard key-value argument.